# JTextArea and GridBagLayout: how to avoid changing column width as we write some text?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jtextarea, gridbaglayout

I would like to design a JFrame whose layout consists in 3 columns:

- a left column containing a text editor (I have chosen a JTextArea);
- center column containing a single button (JButton);
- a right column containing another text editor.

I managed to do this using the GridBagLayout class.
However, when I write some text in an editor, the width of the editor gets larger and the width of the other editor gets smaller.

Could help me to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("My frame");
frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
frame.setLocation(500, 0;

Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
pane.setLayout(layout);

JTextArea textEditor = new JTextArea();

// LEFT TEXT EDITOR
GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
constraints.gridx = 0;
constraints.gridy = 0;
constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
constraints.weightx = 1;
constraints.weighty = 1;
JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
leftPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
leftPanel.add(textEditor);
layout.setConstraints(leftPanel, constraints);
pane.add(leftPanel);

// CENTER BUTTON
constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
constraints.gridx = 1;
constraints.gridy = 0;
constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
JButton button = new JButton("Do");
layout.setConstraints(button, constraints);
pane.add(button);

// RIGHT TEXT EDITOR
constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
constraints.gridx = 2;
constraints.gridy = 0;
contraintes.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
contraintes.weightx = 1;
contraintes.weighty = 1;
JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
rightPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
rightPanel.add(textEditor);
miseEnPage.setConstraints(rightPanel, constraints);
pane.add(rightPanel);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  And make sure the code is indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code i think you should use 2 JTextAreas

and set each JTextArea

```
setLineWrap(true)
```

like so

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("My frame");
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocation(500, 0);

        Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
        GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
        pane.setLayout(layout);

        JTextArea textEditor = new JTextArea();//JTextArea 1
        textEditor.setLineWrap(true);//setLineWrap(true)
        JTextArea textEditor1 = new JTextArea();//JTextArea 2
        textEditor1.setLineWrap(true);//setLineWrap(true)
        // LEFT TEXT EDITOR
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        constraints.weightx = 1;
        constraints.weighty = 1;
        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
        leftPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        leftPanel.add(textEditor);
        layout.setConstraints(leftPanel, constraints);
        pane.add(leftPanel);

        // CENTER BUTTON
        constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.gridx = 1;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        JButton button = new JButton("Do");
        layout.setConstraints(button, constraints);
        pane.add(button);

        // RIGHT TEXT EDITOR
        constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.gridx = 2;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        constraints.weightx = 1;
        constraints.weighty = 1;
        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
        rightPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        rightPanel.add(textEditor1);
        layout.setConstraints(rightPanel, constraints);
        pane.add(rightPanel);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now, the width of the text area does not change but the number of characters per line is too small. Do you know how to overcome this?

Comment: use textEditor.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,500)); and textEditor1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,500)); and correct the dimension depending on how you have your frame